# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quart'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-22.04, quart

Ubuntu 22.10, Python `3.10.7`. I have `Quart = "*"` in `Pipfile`, after running `pipenv install`, still run into this error.